# Error putting data into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, types

I have the following php code:

```
foreach($html->find('dl[class=movie-info]') as $info) {

   for($i = 0; $i <= 20; $i++) {

    $contenido = $info->find('dt',$i)->plaintext;

    if($contenido == 'A&ntilde;o'){
        $year = utf8_encode($info->find('dd',$i)->plaintext);}}}
```

(the code has more if functions)

And a mysql table where I put the content of the variables....

The problem is with the $year content, I need to fill it in a  smallint(5) unsigned.

When I use

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","tdguchiha","phpbb3");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO pablo (forum_id, calidad, titulo, caratula, sinopsis, pais, director, reparto, genero) VALUES ('$forum_id', '$calidad', '$titulo', '$img', '$sinopsis', '$pais', '$director', '$reparto', '$genero')");
mysqli_close($con);
```

All the content is inserted, but when i try to insert `$year` into año with type `smallint(5) unsigned` nothing happens, no row is created...

how can I convert $year to a number (it must be a number) to fill it in that column? or I need to change the column type?

PD: I am learning right now to "play" with mysql

thanks

Comment: What is the MySQL error you receive?

Comment: no error is shown, but it is logical to think that there is one, because the information is not added

Comment: Watch my answer edit for error catching...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in mysql between a number and a string when doing queries. Make sure you include the column name in the list of all the columns:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO pablo (forum_id, calidad, titulo, caratula, sinopsis, pais, director, reparto, genero, year) VALUES ('$forum_id', '$calidad', '$titulo', '$img', '$sinopsis', '$pais', '$director', '$reparto', '$genero', '$year')");
                                                                                                                       ^notice year the column                                                                                             ^now the actual value
```

Just replace year in the column section with the name of your mysql column.

Comment: The problem is that when i put the "año" column and $year value, the row isnt added...

Comment: Show us that code. No point looking at your working code. At give us your error messages.

Comment: @Damien Perhaps this has something to do with the enye in `año`.

Comment: @Leng, yes it might. Not sure about that.

Comment: I have changed "año" to "ano" and nothing changes.

Comment: @minato, then please show us your code that has ano and $year in it. We need to see the broken code.

Comment: my fault, a comma was deleted... the problem was that, the "ñ" character in column name, problem solved thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try casting it to an integer instead of using `utf8_encode`:

```
$year = intval($info->find('dd',$i)->plaintext);
```

Or, in addition to it:

```
$year = intval(utf8_encode($info->find('dd',$i)->plaintext));
```

Can you give us an example of the data?

EDIT:  Damien is right, intval() shouldn't make a difference.

Try echoing out the contents instead, and making sure it's an actual number in the string to do some debugging:

```
if($contenido == 'A&ntilde;o'){
    $year = utf8_encode($info->find('dd',$i)->plaintext);
    echo $year.'<br />';}}}
```

Comment: the info was picked from a filmaffinity.com/es film page like view-source:http://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film731232.html

Comment: @minato That's all well and good, but echo it out to debug what you're actually getting in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Before posting a question to StackOverflow, **identify any error-codes / error-messages and post them with your question**:

```
/* check connection */
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

And:

```
if ( ! mysqli_query( $link, "SELECT ..." )) {
    printf("Errorcode: %d\n", mysqli_errno($link));
}
```

More on the [PHP doc site](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: I have received this error [link](http://postimg.org/image/o01yi175b/) i dont know what it means

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with value type and data you are trying to insert:

```
A smallint is between -32768 and 32767 signed, or 0 and 65535 unsigned.

The (5) represents the display width of the field - if you will try to put 90000 you will be rejected.
```

In your case it should not be a problem (years value I assume) but show us the data you are trying to insert.

I guess that you are parsing some content using simple_html_dom - make sure all data retrieved is 
as you expect before inserting it to DB.

Also: Try changing the type to int(5) and now tell us....

It will be easier to see the query you use (with the year) and a sample of data.

**For error loging and display use:**

```
 $execute = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO pablo ( ....your query..... ")
       or
          printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
```

Have Fun

Comment: this is my simple_html_dom.php [link](http://pastebin.com/pubDD3tj), this my application.php (where i fetch data and make queries) [link](http://pastebin.com/r2acxGWY) and this is a source code of filmaffinity [link](http://pastebin.com/MaPurGHg) hope this would be the information you ask

Comment: after add these lines, I have received this error [link](http://postimg.org/image/o01yi175b/) i dont know what it means

Comment: no, thats not what we need - try adding  `echo htmlentities($year);` to your FOR loop i suspect the data you are recieving is not the the year value or it includes some html entities ( &nbsp; &gr; etc) that are not needed - also a link to the target page (that tou parse may help) another way is to use `inval($year)` and by that PHP will try parse the string to its int value.

Comment: This error means you have an error in the query syntax near the value you are trying to pass - I hope you are "escaping all values before inserting them use : `$thevalue = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$thevalue);` to escape special characters that may break you query.

Comment: Sorry my fault, the problem was a comma that was deleted... the problem was the "ñ" character, it has been changed to "n" and the problem is solved thanks a lot